# Vector space carrying a linear representation of a group

Tags: group-theory, vector-spaces

In the following paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/1804.10306.pdf a *G- invariant* function is defined as

$$f: V \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$$

such that $f(\gamma \cdot x)=f(x) \, \, \, \forall \gamma \in \Gamma$.

But what does it exactly mean that the vector space $V$ **carries** "a linear representation $R: \Gamma \rightarrow GL(V)$"?

Comment: How is $\gamma \cdot x$ defined? And what properties does that definition satisfy?

Comment: Sorry there was a typo in the question. You can think of $\gamma$ as just permuting the coordinates of a given vector $x \in V:=\mathbb{R}^n$, i.e. $G := S_n$

Comment: So $G = \Gamma = S_n$?

Comment: yes sorry for the notation issues

Comment: This just a bit sloppy terminology for the fact that you are given a group-homomorphism $\rho: \Gamma\to GL(V)$. Then $\gamma  \cdot x$ simply means $\rho(\gamma)(x)$.

Comment: Okay. Let me suggest that you hit the "Edit" button to fix those issues, so that any potential answerer won't have to figure out how to navigate around them.